# RazorPages: undefined key in viewData not throwing exception

Tags: asp.net, razor, razor-pages

I'm playing around with Razor Pages in ASP.NET core as a learning exercise and one thing I noticed when I tried to use an undefined key in viewData is that no exception was thrown. I'm assuming this is intended, but I wonder... why? And how should I go about detecting such errors? Seems like it would be easy to make a typo and awfully hard to notice before its too late. An example:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Infodawn.Pages
{
    public class IndexModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;

        public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            // doesn't throw exception, even though viewData["bar"] is undefined:
            ViewData["foo"] = ViewData["bar"];

            // throws exception, as expected:
            Dictionary<string, int> dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();
            int a = dict["bar"];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a ViewData item hasn't been set, it will be `null`. Therefore you should test for null before trying to work with ViewData items:

```
if(ViewData["bar"] != null)
{
    //
}
```

When working with any API that relies on "magic string" (e.g. string indexers) there is an inherent risk of typos working there way into the code and causing errors etc. One generic solution is to use constants to represent the key values.

In Razor Pages, the recommendation is to use [PageModel properties](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/pagemodel) to pass data from the controller to the view instead of ViewData.